# How to exclude specific row from query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a below mentioned table:

```
ID      ID_2        Var1
1       L-1         ADD
2       L-1         DER
3       L-2         ADD
4       L-2         DER
5       L-3         DER
5       L-4         DER
```

I want to fetch only those rows where we don't have any unique id corresponding to `ID_2` value is not equal to `ADD`.

Required Output:

```
ID      ID_2        Var1
5       L-3         DER
5       L-4         DER
```

Comment: Tip: Don't store 'L-'

Comment: @Strawberry Is there any specific reason for this??

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select ID, ID_2, Var1
from
(   select ID, ID_2, Var1
    from tablename
    group by ID, ID_2, Var
    having count(ID) = 1 ) somedata
where not Var1 = 'ADD'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subtable that gets only the ID_2s that have a 'add' in Var1. Then join that back to the main table excluding all matches.

```
select ID, ID_2, Var1
from table join
(select id_2
from table
where var1='ADD'
) a 
on table.ID_2<>a.ID_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one simple query in the following way:

```
SELECT d1.ID, d1.ID_2, d1.Var1
FROM data AS d1
LEFT JOIN data AS d2 ON d1.ID = d2.ID
WHERE d1.Var1 <> 'ADD'
GROUP BY d1.ID_2
HAVING COUNT(d1.ID) > 1;
```

See [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cc339/1).